# The height of the sub reports are not same in report

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a problem when setting the height for each sub report contents inside different.

I have 1 main report and 2 sub report (A & B).

How to set the height of each sub report different?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What do you mean? `How to set the height of each sub report different?` The height is dynamic and depends on the number of rows in report

Comment: difficult for me to explain in detail. I have images that can be explained, but I can not upload to this website

Comment: You can post the links - I'll add images

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gc4q9r39n9aooil/report_temp_subreport1.png

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lhh2qzkh8ehez0b/report_with_subreport2.png