# create a static report templates with data retrieved from sql query

Tags: jasper-reports

how to create report templates with row groups and column groups are static (static text) but the contents of the data retrieved from sql query.

I mean this is like the example below.

```
 _____________________________________________________________________________
|             PENERIMAAN              |             PENGELUARAN               |
|_____________________________________|_______________________________________|
|      Description       |   Amount   |        Description       |   Amount   |
|________________________|____________|__________________________|____________|
| Group Description.1    |            | Group Description.3      |            |
| Description 1.1        |   450,000  | Description 3.1          |  1,250,000 |
| Description 1.2        |   850,000  | Description 3.2          |  4,780,000 |
| Description 1.3        | 1,650,000  | Description 3.3          |    950,000 |
| Description 1.4        | 2,250,000  | Description 3.4          |          - |
|________________________|____________|__________________________|____________|
| Group Description.2    |            | Group Description.4      |            |
| Description 2.1        |   550,000  | Description 4.1          |  1,120,000 |
| Description 2.2        | 1,850,000  | Description 4.2          |          - |
| Description 2.3        |   920,000  | Description 4.3          |     85,500 |
| Description 2.4        |         -  |                          |            |
|________________________|____________|__________________________|____________|
|                                GRAND TOTAL                                  |
|_____________________________________________________________________________|
|              8,520,000              |              8,100,000                |
|_____________________________________|_______________________________________|
```

note: Group Description & Descriptions = Static Text;  nominal / amount (numeric) = fields from sql query.

is there any best solution for me ?

Comment: Can you post your template?

Comment: Hi Alex,
do you still remember to this topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17272238/the-height-of-the-sub-reports-are-not-same-in-report
#I question why there is always -1  (what is wrong?)

Comment: It is the same issue (report)?

Comment: same, differing only in the report data source and table.

Answer (score 0):

Put subReport in amount field.